# Best usage of SuppressWarnings Unused in library

Tags: android, android-library, android-lint

I'm developing an **Android library** and I wanted to clean all warnings. Most of them is due to **unused methods**. I don't want to remove this methods from the class as it could be used by other developer.

Should I:

- **add** `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` on methods or class?
- **remove** the methods anyway?
- **use** this methods in the **project app** that is using the library (for development purpose). This will remove the warning but will add some junk code to the app?
- or?

If I annotate the class to suppress this warnings it will solve the issue but it will also prevent me for removing real unused methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unused warning should only appear if a private method is never used. If a private method is never used, it is indeed dead code, since nobody could call it from outside. You should delete these methods. I hope you are using a version control system, so you can still find methods in the repository history.

Comment: Android Studio display unused for public methods too cf https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ap7k50jhcb366s/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-06-26%2010.51.39.png?dl=0

Comment: You should [disable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26095746/747412) that inspection for public methods, it is incorrect in case of libraries.

Comment: Though not clear in the question, it seems more likely the issue has to do with `public` methods that may actually be used by a project that makes use of the library. In this case, it isn't safe to delete things that AS reports as unused; AS just doesn't know about the usages.

Comment: I only spoke about deleting private methods, and actually said the inspection should be disabled for public ones.

Comment: Hmm, can't find the inspection for "method ... is never used" in Android Studio.  Anyone?