# Enable warning for Unused Enum fields in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums

When IDEA has the following code:

```
final public static String unused="";
```

It will show "unused" in grey with a squiggle underscore and a tooltip that say "Field 'unused' is never used".

However this code:

```
enum MyEnum{
  UNUSED
}
```

does not show the squiggle.  I can run Analyze|Inspect Code to get an "Unused declaration" message in  the "Inspection Results".

Is there a way to make IDEA find the unused fields of an enum automatically when opening the code in the editor?

Answer (score 1):

As said in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166334/disable-not-used-warning-for-public-methods-of-a-class) go to `Settings`|search for `unused declaration` and under `Java` click on that. On the right, there are all available things you can do with it.

Comment: There are checkboxes for Classes, Inner classes, Fields, Methods, Parameters, and Local variables.  They are all checked.  There is not a checkbox for Enums, yet.  v2017.1.3

Comment: you could submit a feature request in IntelliJ website

Comment: I submitted a feature request here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests You can probably do the same.

Answer (score 0):

There might be something else going on. Please check if somewhere in your code you call `MyEnum.values()`

According to this [IDEA bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65298) it's a special request that in that case all `enum` members are considered used. That's a double edged sword as in some cases it's a smell not to have the enum constant referenced in the code.