# Suppressing "unused" warnings for public API functions in Intellij (for Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

There's [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54206041/11377112) to suppress the warnings for Java codebase in IntelliJ.

But seems like there's no option to disable that for Kotlin:

[image]

I'm aware of `@file:Supress("unused")` but that seems to disable whole inspection in the file while I only want to disable it for the public classes and functions, and also for the whole project instead of single file.

My main focus is on a Gradle based solution if possible, otherwise any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This request already exist in [public tracker of Kotlin](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22144). You can subscribe to be notified if the status of a task will change.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ticket! But probably this isn't an answer to the original question:)